# converting a python dictionary to a dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a python dictionary like this example:

small example:

```
dict = {'chr2:173370685-173370692': 'TACCAAG', 'chr5:118309829-118309836': 'TCTCCTT', 'chr12:104659651-104659658': 'GACCAAA'}
```

I only need the value part of every item which is a sequence of letters and the letters are `A, T, C or G` and also the length of each sequence is 7 so, for every sequence of letters there are `7 positions`. I want to get the frequency of the 4 mentioned letters in every position (we have `7` positions). for every position I will make a dictionary in which the letters are key and the frequency of every letter is value. and at the end I want to make a dictionary for all seven positions and the fist dictionary would be the value of the final dictionary.
here is the expected output for the small example:

expected output:

```
final = {one: {'T': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'G': 0}, two: {'T': 0, 'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'G': 0}, three: {'T': 1, 'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'G': 0}, four: {'T': 0, 'A': 0, 'C': 3, 'G': 0}, five: {'T': 0, 'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'G': 0}, six: {'T': 1, 'A': 2, 'C': 0, 'G': 0}, seven: {'T': 1, 'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'G': 1}}
```

to get this output I wrote a code in `python` but it does not return what exactly I want. do you know how to fix the following code?

```
one=[]
two=[]
three=[]
four=[]
five=[]
six=[]
seven=[]
mylist = dict.values()
for threeq in mylist:
    one.append(threeq[0])
    two.append(threeq[1])
    three.append(threeq[2])
    four.append(threeq[3])
    five.append(threeq[4])
    six.append(threeq[5])
    seven.append(threeq[6])


from collections import Counter

one=Counter(one)    
two=Counter(two)
three=Counter(three)
four=Counter(four)
five=Counter(five)
six=Counter(six)
seven=Counter(seven)
```

Comment: the expected output is unclear, can you clarify?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest   the expected output is a dictionary with 7 items. the keys are one to seven since there are seven positions (length of every sequence of letters is 7) and the values are another dictionary in which the keys are the letters (the letters are A, T, G or C) and the values are the frequency of each letter. is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it, using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

data = {'chr2:173370685-173370692': 'TACCAAG', 'chr5:118309829-118309836': 'TCTCCTT', 'chr12:104659651-104659658': 'GACCAAA'}

out = {i:Counter(col) for i, col in enumerate(zip(*(data.values()))) }

# we can add the missing keys whose count is 0:
for count in out.values():
    count.update(dict.fromkeys('ATGC', 0))

print(out)

# {0: Counter({'T': 2, 'G': 1, 'A': 0, 'C': 0}), 1: Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'T': 0, 'G': 0}), 
#  2: Counter({'C': 2, 'T': 1, 'A': 0, 'G': 0}), 3: Counter({'C': 3, 'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0}), 
#  4: Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'T': 0, 'G': 0}), 5: Counter({'A': 2, 'T': 1, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}), 
 # 6: Counter({'G': 1, 'T': 1, 'A': 1, 'C': 0})}
```

I left the original indices as integers, it's probably easier to use them than strings like 'one', 'two'... But if you really want to:

```
numbers_as_strings = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
out = {numbers_as_strings[key]:value for key, value in out.items()}
print(out)
# {'one': Counter({'T': 2, 'G': 1, 'A': 0, 'C': 0}), 
#  'two': Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'T': 0, 'G': 0}) ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
values = list(dict.values())
r = {}
for i in range(7):
    r[i+1] = {'T': 0, 'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0}
    for v in values:
        r[i+1][v[i]] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {'chr2:173370685-173370692': 'TACCAAG', 'chr5:118309829-118309836': 'TCTCCTT', 'chr12:104659651-104659658': 'GACCAAA'}
options=['T','A','C','G']
innerdicts=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']
def getposcount(idx,letter,dict):
    count=0
    for v in dict.values():
        if v[idx]==letter:
            count+=1
    return count

d = {x:{y:getposcount(innerdicts.index(x),y,dict) for y in options} for x in innerdicts}
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'six': {'T': 1, 'A': 2, 'G': 0, 'C': 0}, 'one': {'T': 2, 'A': 0, 'G': 1, 'C': 0}, 'two': {'T': 0, 'A': 2, 'G': 0, 'C': 1}, 'five': {'T': 0, 'A': 2, 'G': 0, 'C': 1}, 'three': {'T': 1, 'A': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 2}, 'seven': {'T': 1, 'A': 1, 'G': 1, 'C': 0}, 'four': {'T': 0, 'A': 0, 'G': 0, 'C': 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept the integers as keys, you can do:

```
from collections import Counter


def counts_with_zero(count, keys='TACG'):
    return {key: count.get(key, 0) for key in keys}


d = {'chr2:173370685-173370692': 'TACCAAG', 'chr5:118309829-118309836': 'TCTCCTT',
     'chr12:104659651-104659658': 'GACCAAA'}

values = list(d.values())
result = {i: counts_with_zero(Counter(column)) for i, column in enumerate(zip(*values), 1)}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{1: {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
 2: {'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
 3: {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'G': 0, 'T': 1},
 4: {'A': 0, 'C': 3, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
 5: {'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
 6: {'A': 2, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 1},
 7: {'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'G': 1, 'T': 1}}
```